# how post data through url to database using Web services in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i have 3 text fields,i want to post user entered data into data base through url.
I have url which is connected to data base,but  in my code below.
connection is successful,but when i post data in three UITextfields(name,age ,salary),values
stored in database is showing null.
i want to check values entered in textFields in data base.
plz an any one tell me what changes i should do in my code to post data.

.H

#import

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{






    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *age;

    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *Name;

    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *Salary;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *age;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Salary;



- (IBAction)send:(id)sender;




@end
```

.M

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{


    NSMutableData *recievedData;
NSMutableData *webData;
    NSURLConnection *connection;
    NSMutableArray *array;
    NSMutableString *first;


}
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize age;
@synthesize Name;
@synthesize Salary;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender {
    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?&username=%@&password=%@&emailid=%@",
                     age.text, Name.text,Salary.text];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.3.170:8090/RestWebService/rest/person"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(conn)
    {      webData=[NSMutableData data];
        NSLog(@"Connection successfull");
        NSLog(@"GOOD Day My data %@",webData);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"connection could not be made");

    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength:0];
    NSLog(@"DidReceiveResponse");
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"DidReceiveData");
    NSLog(@"DATA %@",data);
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error is");
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[webData length]);
    NSLog(@"Data is %@",webData);



    // NSLog(@"receivedData%@",_receivedData);

    NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseText);//holds textfield entered value

    NSLog(@"");

    NSString *newLineStr = @"\n";
    responseText = [responseText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br />" withString:newLineStr];

    NSLog(@"ResponesText %@",responseText);


}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Comment: simple, r u need the sample code for post the data to server

Comment: are you get "responseText" from server ?

Comment: @anbu.Karthik thanks for Reply, yes i want sample code for post the data to server please post that code

Answer (score 0):

Sample App with tutorial

[connecting-to-php-service-from-ios](http://divcode.blogspot.com/2012/08/connecting-to-php-service-from-ios.html)

or

Handle your result data with help of NSURLConnection delegate methods

```
  NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",@"Raja",@"deepi"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/promos/index.php"]];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if( theConnection ){
        // indicator.hidden = NO;
        mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
```

your PHP code

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

//check your condition 



    echo $result;
?>
```